# Function to approximate skewed distribution of range of values?

Tags: c#, python, statistics, distribution

I need to write a function that will return an IEnumerable> where each Tuple represents each member of a generated range along with a corresponding probability that would approximate a probability on a skewed distribution.

I envision a function signature of:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> SkewedRange(double min, double max, double mean, double step = 1.0)
```

For example, a range between 1.0 and 10.0 with mean 2.3 and default step 1.0, I want a list of values like so:

```
Item1  Item2  Histogram (for demo only)
1.0    p1     *****
2.0    p2     *********
3.0    p3     *******
4.0    p3     *****
5.0    p3     ***
6.0    p3     **
7.0    p3     **
8.0    p3     *
9.0    p3     *
10.0   p10    *
```

The resulting graph of these values would resemble a skewed distribution whose peak was between 2-3.

Questions:

1. Is this feasible. If so, on a scale of 1 to 5 how difficult to implement.
2. Are there any open source libraries that could be utilized or already implement something like this.
3. Any resources anyone knows of to help someone like me understand this problem domain. I have done a significant amount of research on this already, but everything is heavy in statistic theory with equations using notation that is very difficult for a non-statistician to consume much less codify.
4. Anything else I am not considering here?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: This is a very specific programming problem so it is very 'on topic'. What exactly is your grievance with how I asked?

Comment: Something like this shouldn't be hard to write, but I'm not sure you can get away from understanding statistics.  What kind of a distribution do you require?  If you know, you probably have an equation for it.

Comment: That is encouraging. I majored in CS and minored in math, but some of the notation used in statistics is very domain specific. The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128781/whats-the-formula-for-the-probability-density-function-of-skewed-normal-distribu/1128788#1128788) seems promising - I just can't get past the notation in the equations supplied. Also, I think just a skewed normal distribution would suffice for this particular problem.

Comment: @Casey: I see all four of your questions as off-topic: (1) Opinion-based; (2) & (3) Off-site resources; (3) General tutoring; (4) Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is to sample from distribution which is truncated to a given range and which has its mode (greatest density) in that range.

I'll assume that it doesn't matter very much exactly what's the distribution. So I assume a truncated normal distribution is OK.

Let a and b be some numbers. These describe the bump. Let c and d be some other numbers. These specify the range.

Let x be a random sample from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1. There is probably a function for this in C# but I don't know what it might be named. Then a + b x is also normal, with mean a and variance b^2.

If a + b x is between c and d, then output that as one sample. Otherwise try again until you get a number between c and d.

You can vary a, b, c, and d and see what you get. Hope this helps.